# Smallest number ended in 6 that changin a digit of place becomes four times itself

Tags: divisibility, congruences

Find the smallest natural $$n$$ such that it’s decimal representation ends at 6 and that if the digit 6 is moved to the beginning of the number (e.i. if the original number was $$x1x2...xm6$$ the new number will be $$6x1x2...xm$$) the resulting number is four times the original.

I've found those numbers by doing the multiplication, I mean, since $$4*x1x2...xm6=6x1x2...xm$$ then $$xm$$ must be 4 and through that way I get the numbers $$153846$$ and $$615384$$. I want to know how to get there more formally.

Comment: Your notation is akward, but in essence you are asking for the smallest $k$ digit number $n$ such that $4(10n+6)=6\cdot 10^{k-1}+n$.  Moving everything to one side and plugging in various values of $k$, we get a single solution for $n$ for each but the solution is a non-integer for smaller values of $k$ until reaching $k=6$.  Using $k=6$ and moving everything to one side and factoring we get $39(n-15384)=0$. implying that the original number was indeed $153846$.

Comment: OEIS has sequences containing your number, including [A034089](https://oeis.org/A034089).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the number formed by the digits after $6$ be $x$ then the number is $10x+6$ and it satisfies 
\begin{eqnarray*}
4(10x+6)=6 \times 10^k +x
\end{eqnarray*}
where $k$ is the number of digits in $x$. From the eqqation we have $13x=2(10^k-4)$ so we require $ 10^k \equiv 4 \pmod{13}$. Now calculate the powers of $10$ modulo $13$; $10,9,12,3,\color{red}{4}$.
So $k=5$ , $(10^5 -4) /13 = 7692$ and $x=15384$. So $153846 \times 4 = 615384$.

Comment: Smart. It works for every $k$ that is $-1$ modulo $6$. Then $10x+6$ gives $153846, 153846153846, 153846153846153846, 153846153846153846153846, \ldots$. But the askers method of "school multiplication" was also smart.